# header&footer not displayed in different browsers, diplayed only main text

Tags: html

I am trying to create webpage using below mentioned code and jquery-3.4.1.js; Problem is, all webpage is correctly displayed in MicrosoftEdge, other browser do not display header nor footer.
What should I do more? Using html5.

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("#header").load("header.html");
$("#footer").load("footer.html");
});
</script>

<body>
<div id="header"></div>
other text
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you see anything in the console on the other browsers?

Comment: microsoft edge displays good. tried opera, firefox, msie, no success. footer&header not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(function(){
$("#header").load("header.html");
$("#footer").load("footer.html");
});
});
</script>

<body>
<div id="header"></div>
other text
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```